# nginx proxy fail2ban on 401

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, fail2ban

In the setup I've right now I've NGINX that works as proxy for (serveral) internal VMs. Now, I would like to protect these VMs from bruteforce, such that, if there's a huge amount of 401 the IP should be blocked.

I've google around on how to use fail2ban, but I can't figure out how it can work in my case.

The `access.log` of nginx looks like this (i've hidden some sensitive infos)

```
148.XXX.XXX.XXX - 92....396 [09/Jan/2017:13:43:32 +0100] "POST /v1/schemas/7...b8/documents HTTP/1.1" 200 364 "-" "python-requests/2.10.0"
148.XXX.XXX.XXX - 92....396 [09/Jan/2017:13:43:32 +0100] "DELETE /v1/documents/fd7...09e1?force=true HTTP/1.1" 200 83 "-" "python-requests/2.10.0"
148.XXX.XXX.XXX - 92....396 [09/Jan/2017:13:43:32 +0100] "GET /v1/schemas/713e4ee8-...b8/documents HTTP/1.1" 200 6689 "-" "python-requests/2.10.0"
47.XXX.XXX.XXX - - [09/Jan/2017:13:43:33 +0100] "GET /wp-login.php HTTP/1.1" 301 178 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:40.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/40.1"
47.XXX.XXX.XXX - - [09/Jan/2017:13:43:39 +0100] "GET /wp-login.php HTTP/1.1" 301 178 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:40.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/40.1"
47.XXX.XXX.XXX - - [09/Jan/2017:13:43:44 +0100] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 301 178 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:40.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/40.1"
148.XXX.XXX.XXX - 92....396 [09/Jan/2017:13:44:33 +0100] "GET /v1/schemas/713e4e...d649b8/documents HTTP/1.1" 200 6689 "-" "python-requests/2.10.0"
148.XXX.XXX.XXX - 92....396 [09/Jan/2017:13:44:33 +0100] "POST /v1/schemas/713e4..fd649b8/documents HTTP/1.1" 200 364 "-" "python-requests/2.10.0"
148.XXX.XXX.XXX - 92....396 [09/Jan/2017:13:44:33 +0100] "DELETE /v1/documents/9f5....cadf29031c?force=true HTTP/1.1" 200 83 "-" "python-requests/2.10.0"
148.XXX.XXX.XXX - 92....396 [09/Jan/2017:13:44:33 +0100] "GET /v1/schemas/713e...649b8/documents HTTP/1.1" 200 6689 "-" "python-requests/2.10.0"
87.XXX.XXX.XXX - {{customerId [09/Jan/2017:13:45:08 +0100] "GET /v1/repositories HTTP/1.1" 401 101 "-" "PostmanRuntime/3.0.9"
87.XXX.XXX.XXX - {{customerId [09/Jan/2017:13:45:09 +0100] "GET /v1/repositories HTTP/1.1" 401 101 "-" "PostmanRuntime/3.0.9"
87.XXX.XXX.XXX - test [09/Jan/2017:13:45:20 +0100] "GET /v1/repositories HTTP/1.1" 401 101 "-" "PostmanRuntime/3.0.9"
```

As you can see, NGINX works as proxy for the service and for the website and other services. What i would like to prevent are the last 3 lines, where the return code is 401.

As far I understood (mostly [from here](https://snippets.aktagon.com/snippets/554-how-to-secure-an-nginx-server-with-fail2ban)) I could make a regexp to intercept that lines that contains a 401, setting a burstime of 3600 (60 mins lock) and retries of 100. So that 100 errors per hours are permitted.

**Note**: I've to figure out this value (any idea?), it may happen that someone gets 401 every now and then.

Yet, I know the thoery but not yet the practice. Can someone help me in setting this up especially on how to write the regexp for that condition.

I came up with `^<HOST>.* 401` **but don't know if it's enough** and I would like to avoid to block everybody by mistake.

After finding the regexp, I should add this rule to a file (let's call it `nginx-401.conf` under `/etc/fail2ban/filter.d/` that will look like

```
[Definition]
failregex = ^<HOST> -.* 401
ignoreregex =
```

and in `jail.conf`

```
[nginx-401]
enabled = true
action = iptables-multiport[name=NoProxy, port="http,https"] # no idea of this, copied from somewhere else. what should I put here?
filter = nginx-401 # should be the file name 
logpath = /var/log/nginx*/*access*.log
maxretry = 100 # my limit
bantime  = 3600 # 1 hour
```

Here I don't really have idea of what `action` should be and if the rest is set up correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Login dialog page itself is returned with 401 code.

Failed logins are logged with syntax:

```
<host> - <user> [06/Jun/2018:11:18:55 +0300] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 401 ...
```

...where given username is in '<user>' and return code is 401

```
[Definition]
failregex = ^<HOST> - [^-[ ]+.+HTTP/1.[0-9]" 401
ignoreregex =
```

This regex will not match login attempts with empty username. In that case the username would be '-' which is inseparable from the login dialog page.

Comment: How would I match a path like /api/1/login

Answer (score 0):

In the end it seems to work, this is my conf just for reference:
`/etc/fail2ban/filter.d/wrongauth.conf`

```
[Definition]
failregex = ^<HOST> -.* 401
ignoreregex =
```

in `/etc/fail2ban/jail.con`

```
[wrongauth]
enabled = true
filter = wrongauth
action = shorewall 
    %(mta)s-whois-lines[name=%(__name__)s, dest="%(destemail)s", logpath=%(logpath)s, chain="%(chain)s", sendername="%(sendername)s"]
logpath = /var/log/nginx*/*access*.log
banTime = 600 # 10 minutes
findTime = 60
maxretry = 60
```

As action I use shorewall, and to send email when the ban occurs I had to modifiy the action accordingly to the setting that you see.

Comment: just noticed that the regexp takes anything that has `401` in one of the fields.. so not the rule i was looking for